# " How much before?" VS "How earlier" VS "How much earlier?"

Tags: grammar, meaning, idiomatic-language, questions, colloquial-language

I imagined myself talking to a doctor in English, so I made up this conversation.

**A: You should take this medicine before the meals.**

**B: ................?** (Here, I need a question that would require the doctor to specify a certain time)

**A: 2 hours before the meals.**

This kind of conversation is often used in daily life. However, I could not be sure how to ask about the amounf of time when it comes to specify the beforeNESS with regards to the time of medication.

I think of the following alternatives:

**1- How much before?**

**2- How earlier?**

**3- How much earlier?**

**4- How long earlier?**

I think number 1 sounds good to me as a non-native speaker, but the others also seem to make sense grammatically. However, I can't be sure. So, which one would be the most common or the most correct?

Comment: The doctor would say 'before meals'.

Comment: @KateBunting, I didn't know that. Thanks. However, I thought the article "the" would be necessary if, by meals, I am referring to the 3 times of eating during the day, now the kind of dishes.

Comment: Yes, I know you are. The standard instruction is "Take three times a day before meals".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for 2 (which is ungrammatical), they all could work,  I'd probably opt for "How long before?"

Or a more "natural" conversational ploy is to suggest an answer and ask for confirmation: "Do you mean immediately before I eat?"